# JOOQ ignores exclusion regex

Tags: java, spring-boot, jooq

I would like to avoid code generation for table partitions (only main table is enough). I am using the instructions provided [here](https://blog.jooq.org/integrating-jooq-with-postgresql-partitioning/)

My partitioned tables are named like `events_p2022_05_10` so I am using a config like

```
<regexMatchesPartialQualification>true</regexMatchesPartialQualification>
<includes>.*</includes>
<excludes>.*_p[0-9]+</excludes>
```

However the partition tables are generated regardless. What am I missing? I am using version 3.16.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex only matches complete identifiers (qualified or unqualified). Your regex doesn't match your identifier. You probably meant to write this?

```xml
<excludes>.*_p[0-9_]+</excludes>
```

Note the added `_`

Comment: Thanks so much that worked. So it is not possible filter with a partial match right?

Comment: @CemreMengü: I mean... `.*something.*`